# What is most preferred HTML+CSS framework (No Javascript) to make cross browser UI elemets like iPhone?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

What is most preferred HTML+CSS framework (No Javascript) to make mobile websites?

Mainly I want to make iPhone like button, tabs, transitions, form elements, on-off buttons with etc with CSS3 only. but websites should run well on iphone and Android and latest Blackberry mobiles.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658663/css-frameworks-for-mobile-dev though there are a few JS solutions in there.

Answer (score 1):

foneFrame is a mobile framework built with HTML5 + CSS3 that creates mobile pages for smartphones like Android & iPhone. Lightweight & extensible. www.QRdvark.com/foneFrame/

Answer (score -1):

Why no javascript? Seems an odd decision really – the reason why so much is cross compatible is because of JS running. JS also lets you write more managable code, whilst still including transitions etc – CSS transitions are limited if you aren't able to juggle the elements you are using.

I'd recommend jQuery Mobile, despite the fact it uses JS.

Comment: I thought if something can be possible without JavaScript then we should go for that and JS rendering is heavier and Speed is also a big point of concern on mobile, because of costly Data Plans and slow bandwidth connectivity. But OK as you have given the reason of benefit of using JavaScript then I will go for jQuery Mobile. but some time we need more customization in design rather then default jQuery mobile themes.

Comment: And I'm only considering Web-Based browsers so I thought most of the things I need can be possible in CSS 3 only.

Comment: You'll typically save bandwidth by using JS, as you can use templates to avoid transferring the same thing over and over. CSS3 will go a long way, but you'll often want JS to help you deal with it.