# Looking for a pure css ui framework for mobile web

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am looking for a CSS framework to style form elements and lists that are big and easy to use on small screens. It needs to be a CSS only framework, with little or no JavaScript. Something like Twitter Bootstrap. I do not want a JavaScript-heavy framework like jQueryMobile. Responsive layout and grid-support are not needed as well.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658663/css-frameworks-for-mobile-dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like a iOS-style framework you can try [iWebKit](http://snippetspace.com/) and [iUI](http://www.iui-js.org).

You could also use any responsive framework, like Bootstrap.